# finding best fit model using AIC in Panel Data using R

Tags: panel-data, aic

I am currently trying to find a best model using R for Panel Data. I have a project on Corporate Governance in which I collected data of various companies from 2009-2014. I found the best fit using Backward Elimination and Forward Selection using T values in R which concur with themselves (I think its expected as well). But, after reading various articles in academic community I realize T values can give dubious results and to gain any sort of credibility for my results it will be best to use AIC or BIC criteria (even though its not a big improvement by the looks of things in terms of credibility but still its some improvement). As I understand, the definition of AIC is as follows:

AIC = -2log-likelihood+2p     (for BIC it will be plogn)

For normal data with no time series, R has a pre-defined function stepAIC which selects variables according to AIC values till AIC value cannot decrease.

But for panel data I havent found any way to find AIC value. I have tried searching for this but in vain.

Comment: Stepwise regression should be avoided, for reasons that are well documented on this site.  It is not only not good for prediction; it distorts all aspects of statistical inference.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know it is an old Question but i had a similar problem:

I ended up using the lmer/lme4 packages and I was able to force option="ML" to force the use of the conventional Maximum likelihood function, instead of using the REML (restricted maximum likelihood) default option. so stepAIC from mass package could optimize by AIC.

Comment: What do you mean by force a ML function?

Comment: mdewey - rlme functions by defaust uses  “restricted maximum likelihood” method (REML) and I couldnt find a way to optimize by AIC using this REML default option. but I was able to run the optimization by AIC if setting the option="ML", using the standar Maximum likelihood function.     please refer to: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48671/what-is-restricted-maximum-likelihood-and-when-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 0):

I found this some years ago (I don't remember where):

````
aicbic_plm <- function(object, criterion) {
  
  
  # object is "plm", "panelmodel" 
  # Lets panel data has index :index = c("Country", "Time")
  
  sp = summary(object)
  
  if(class(object)[1]=="plm"){
    u.hat <- residuals(sp) # extract residuals
    df <- cbind(as.vector(u.hat), attr(u.hat, "index"))
    names(df) <- c("resid", "Country", "Time")
    c = length(levels(df$Country)) # extract country dimension 
t = length(levels(df$Time)) # extract time dimension 
    np = length(sp$coefficients[,1]) # number of parameters
n.N = nrow(sp$model) # number of data
    s.sq  <- log( (sum(u.hat^2)/(n.N))) # log sum of squares
    
    # effect = c("individual", "time", "twoways", "nested"),
    # model = c("within", "random", "ht", "between", "pooling", "fd")
    
    # I am making example only with some of the versions:
    
    if (sp$args$model == "within" & sp$args$effect == "individual"){
      n = c
      np = np+n+1 # update number of parameters
    }
    
    if (sp$args$model == "within" & sp$args$effect == "time"){
      T = t
      np = np+T+1 # update number of parameters
    }
    
    if (sp$args$model == "within" & sp$args$effect == "twoways"){
      n = c
      T = t
      np = np+n+T # update number of parameters
    }
    aic <- round(       2*np  +  n.N * (  log(2*pi) + s.sq  + 1 ),1)
    bic <- round(log(n.N)*np  +  n.N * (  log(2*pi) + s.sq  + 1 ),1)
    
    if(criterion=="AIC"){
      names(aic) = "AIC"
      return(aic)
    }
    if(criterion=="BIC"){
      names(bic) = "BIC"
      return(bic)
    }
  }
}
```
````