# Deriving the maximum likelihood of REML for linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, linear-algebra, reml

Consider the linear model $Y = X \beta + e$, $e \sim N(0, V(\theta))$, where $Y$ is a $n \times 1$ vector, $X$ is the $n \times p$ full rank design matrix, $V(\theta)$ is the covariance matrix. I drop $\theta$ below for convenient expression.

B is an $n \times (n-p)$ matrix whose columns are orthonormal basis of $C(X)^{\perp}$. REML maximizes the likelihood of $B^T Y$, which can be expressed as

$$ L(\theta) = (2 \pi)^{-(n-p)/2} |B^T V B|^{-1/2} \text{exp} \{- \frac{1}{2} Y^T B (B^T V B)^{-1} B^T Y \} \tag{1} $$ where $|A|$ is the determinant of matrix $A$.

This can be proved to be equivalent as

$$L(\theta) = (2 \pi)^{-(n-p)/2} |X^T X|^{1/2} |V|^{-1/2} |X^T V^{-1} X|^{-1/2} \text{exp} \{- \frac{1}{2} Y^T V^{-1} (I - Q) Y \} \tag{2} $$ where $Q = X (X^T V^{-1} X)^{-1}X^T V^{-1}$.

I am able to prove that $$I - Q = V B (B^T V B)^{-1} B^T \tag{3} $$ by showing that they are the same projection operator onto $C(VB)$ along $C(X)$, and thus prove the $\text{exp}$ part.

However, I don't know how to prove

$$|B^T V B| = |X^T X|^{-1} |V| |X^T V^{-1} X| \tag{4} $$

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: Can you please add the source of these derivations?

Comment: I use my notation in the derivation, but there are some sources. For example, page 20 of this [paper](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=9681&context=rtd). Also, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205485/how-are-calculations-done-for-reml) is another relevant post, citing "Harville 1974 showed that".

Comment: Note that it is obvious when $V=$ identity since
$B^\top V B = B^\top B = I_{n-p}$ then. So this is a question about
dot product.

Comment: @Yves Sorry I still fail to get the point. Could you please elaborate on how to use dot product to show the equality? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I thought that orthonormality related to the dot product
$<y, y'> := y^\top V^{-1}y'$ (which is not the case) and that the
result would come by transformation. It seems to be quite tricky, and
I will try to understand ``Harville 1974'' or later references that
might be more detailed.

Comment: This article by Lynn R. LaMotte 
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-006-0335-6
can be relevant (I do not have access to it). You could also
compute the derivative of $\log\{|V||X^\top V^{-1} X||B^\top VB|^{-1}\}$
w.r.t. the matrix $V$ to show that this is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @Yves, the proof of the identity is listed as Proposition 2 in the paper [a direct derivation of the reml likelihood function](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-006-0335-6) by Lynn R. LaMotte. Because the paper may not be open accessed, I show the proof here with slight change of notation.

Because $\begin{pmatrix} X & B \end{pmatrix}$ is a n by n matrix with $B^T X = 0$, we have

\begin{align} |B^T B| |X^T X| |V| &=  |V| | \begin{pmatrix} X^TX & X^TB \\ B^TX & B^TB \end{pmatrix} | \tag{5} \\
&= | \begin{pmatrix} X^T \\ B^T \end{pmatrix} V \begin{pmatrix} X & B \end{pmatrix} | \tag{6} \\
&= |\begin{pmatrix} X^T V X & X^T V B \\ B^T V X & B^T V B \end{pmatrix}| \\
&= |B^T V B| |X^T V X - X^T V B (B^T V B)^{-1} B^T V X| \tag{7} \\
&= |B^T V B | |X^T [V - V B (B^T V B)^{-1} B^T V] X| \\
&= |B^T V B | |X^T X (X^T V^{-1} X)^{-1} X^T X| \tag{8} \\
&= |B^T V B | |X^T X|^2 |X^T V^{-1} X|^{-1}  \tag{9} \end{align}

where (5) and (7) follows from [rule of determinant of block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), (6) and (9) follows from the [rule of determinant of product of square matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb), and (8) follows from (3). Finally, using the fact that $B^T B = I$ (orthonormal basis), (4) is proved.