# Modeling Serial Values with Mixed-Effects Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, repeated-measures

My data has 264 subjects with their serial measurements. Event is death and sataset has 67 dead, 197 alive observations.

I'm trying to model repeated x and y measurements along with age and gender characteristics via Mixed - Effects Logistic Regression Model. My R code is below:

> mel <- glmer(status ~ x + y + age + gender + (1 | time)+ (1|id), data = mydata, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))

When I use this code, I encounter overfitting (I'm not sure this word is the best one to explain the situation). I mean, before modelling I have 67 events, after modelling, I have again 67 events, as predicted probabilities suggest.

On the other hand, when I try to model these repeated values via this other code below, it gave me an error like this:

> mel <- glmer(status ~ x + y+age+gender+  (1 | time), data = mydata, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
>
> Warning message: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), optpar,ctrl=controlpar,ctrl=controlcheckConv, : Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue - Rescale variables?

I'd like to know, if I'm missing something or doing it wrong.

---

Part of my data looks like this:

> id time    age gender  x   y

1   0   61  1   3,814621015 1,961307217

> 

1   1   61  1   3,63347795  2,044523568

> 

1   2   61  1   3,421073664 2,037971697

> 

1   5   61  1   3,148801558 2,359346485

> 

2   0   60  1   4,180261483 3,695965805

> 

2   3   60  1   3,421073664 1,758059625

> 

2   4   60  1   4,363847995 0,827560091

> 

2   5   60  1   5,335078126 2,799822309

> 

3   0   61  0   2,988464864 -2,037793335

> 

3   2   61  0   2,967471914 -1,722773861

> 

3   3   61  0   2,410342633 -1,59529577

> 

When I check the numeric and factor variables, R again gave another error:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> unable to evaluate scaled gradient
> 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

I got confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? Have you checked that the numeric variables are considered numeric by R, and the factors are factors?

Comment: For similar issues, some suggest that the dataset is too small https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205633/after-trying-various-optimzers-model-simplification-running-more-iterations-wh or that the issue is caused by the use of the BOBYQA optimiser https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/model-failed-to-converge-warning-in-lmer