# P values from lmer with lmerTest - why REML= TRUE?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, p-value, glmm

I would like to obtain p-values from my model fit with `lmer()`from the `lme4` package.

It looks something like this:

`model4<- lmer(rt~ a + b + c + a*b*c + (1|id), data= dat, REML= FALSE)`

I compared the model to less complex models with an LRT-Test via `anova()` and thus set `REML=FALSE`.

Now, I would like to analyse contrasts in my model `model4` and obtain p values.

I read about the package `lmerTest` and thought about using satterthwaite method:

```
library(lmerTest)
fit<- as(model4, "merModLmerTest")
anova(fit)
```

R gives me an output which looks good.

however, I read that my model needs to be fit by `REML=TRUE`.

Did I fit my model wrong, then?
And why do I need to fit `REML=TRUE`?

I am confused and would be glad if somebody helped me out!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48671/what-is-restricted-maximum-likelihood-and-when-should-it-be-used

Comment: Thank you! So it is okay to "mix" the methods?

Comment: As the answers in the provided link state, REML is used to get better estimates, while ML is used to compare models. You can compare models using ML, and then select the best one and use REML.